# how to pre-fill the values of a dynamic HTML table from a text file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have the following code in jsfiddle,
http://jsfiddle.net/y3x4q/

JavaScript:

```
         function buildTable(val)
      {
   var myTable =document.getElementById("contentTable");
 var j=val;
var r1=val;
var rows = [];
var cells = [];

while (myTable.hasChildNodes()) {
myTable.removeChild(myTable.lastChild);
}


for( var i = 0; i < 1; i++ )
{
rows[i] = myTable.insertRow(i);
if(i%3==2)rows[i].addClass("every3rdrow");
cells[i] = [];

for( var x = 0; x < j ; x++ )
{
    cells[i][x] =document.createElement((x==0)?"th":"td");
    cells[i][x].innerHTML = (x==0)?"<input id=t onchange=ty() name=t[] size=3>":"<input id=t1 onchange=ty1() name=t1[] size=3>";
    rows[rows.length - 1].appendChild(cells[i][x]);
}
 }

  }
  buildTable();
```

HTML:

```
  <tr>
   <th>Number of Models:<title="Number of Models"></th>

   <td><select id="numbermodels" name="numbermodels" onmouseover="buildTable(this.value)" onchange="buildTable(this.value);buildTable4(this.value);">

    <option value="1">1</option >
   <option selected="selected" value="2">2</option >
      < option value="3">3</option >
    <option value="4">4</option >
   <option value="5">5</option >
    <option value="6">6</option >
    </select></td>
     </tr><br>

     <tr>
     <th>Number of heads per model:</th>
      <td>
    <table id="contentTable" border="1" name="contentTable">
    <!-- Fill table programmatically -->
   </table></td>
      </tr>
```

how i can fill the values of the table on-load from an external text file ?
i have tried to use php tags inside javascript, but i couldn't get it that way,
can this be achieved by using getElementsByTagName ? how to do this ?

Comment: unfortunately `getElementsByTagName` does not get text files, it only gets .... wait for it .... DOM elements by Tag Name !

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/y3x4q/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is using AJAX if you are attempting to get content from an external file on load. So use AJAX to get the data and probably JQuery to parse the data into your table. You won't be able to use a CSS file. I would almost guess using an HTML file would be easiest. Is there a reason you are using an external text file instead of an array?

Comment: @Sachin, make sure you are using a plain text file. It would be sketchy using a .css file as it is meant to contain a style sheet not raw text values. I believe there is a way to parse a .CSV with JQ.

Comment: I know this is a bit late, but why not use a .JSON file? If you have not already figured it out?